# Merge excel cells with C# using Interop.Excel

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I would like to merge several sequences of cells in order to form table header groupings.
I keep the information about the merged cell's value and it's column span in

```
List<Tuple<string, int>>
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
      appExcel.DisplayAlerts = false;

      int columnCellIndex = 1;
      foreach(var captionGroupInfo in extraCaptionGroupings)
      {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range currRange = newWorksheet.Range[newWorksheet.Cells[1, columnCellIndex], 
        newWorksheet.Cells[1, columnCellIndex + captionGroupInfo.Item2]];
        currRange.Value2 = captionGroupInfo.Item1;
        currRange.Select();
        currRange.Merge(Missing.Value);

        columnCellIndex += captionGroupInfo.Item2;
       }
      }
```

So instead of:

```
|    ||     Dog 1    ||     Dog 2    ||      Cat     ||  Hamster 1  ||   Hamster 2  ||  
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id ||Name|Owner|Age||Name|Owner|Age||Name|Owner|Age||Nam|Owner|Age||Name|Owner|Age||
```

I get

```
|                                         Dogs                                     |  
| Id ||Name|Owner|Age|Name|Owner|Age||Name|Owner|Age||Nam|Owner|Age|Name|Owner|Age||
```

It seems to merge all cells in 1.
Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Even if I increase columnCellIndex only by 1, still the result is not what I expect.

Comment: what is the expected result? did not understand your question

Comment: let's say we have 2 dogs, 1 cat and 2 hamsters. I would like to build a row with 5 merged header cells that span through the information of each animal(3 cells). Instead I get only 1 merged cell that span over the all of the information.

Comment: This line will merge row 1's columns 1 to 5 `Range currRange = workSheet.Range[workSheet.Cells[1,1], workSheet.Cells[1, 5]]; currRange.Merge(Missing.Value);` You have the code to merge, it appears the values you are getting are off and they seem to come from `captionGroupInfo.Item2`. So I would start by looking there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I can not see what the values are from `captionGroupInfo.Item2` I am kind of guessing here. From your displayed output, I am guessing that you do not mean to merge the first column. It looks like a single non-merged column. So when you set columnCellIndex = 1; then you are starting from the first column. So I changed the starting column index to 2 because this appears to be where you want to start merging cells. Then I subtracted the ending column index value by 1 when getting the range for a merge. Otherwise the range will be ONE to many because we started at column 2 not column 1. With these changes it worked fine when I tested the returned values from `captionGroupInfo.Item2` where they were 3 cells merge, 3 cells merge, 5 cells merge, 5, etc. It worked as expected with these changes. Hope this helps.

```
int columnCellIndex = 2;
foreach (var captionGroupInfo in extraCaptionGroupings)
{
  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range currRange = newWorksheet.Range[newWorksheet.Cells[1, columnCellIndex], 
                                                                      newWorksheet.Cells[1, columnCellIndex + captionGroupInfo.Item2 - 1]];
  currRange.Value2 = captionGroupInfo.Item1;
  currRange.Select();
  currRange.Merge(Missing.Value);
  columnCellIndex += captionGroupInfo.Item2;
}
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks a lot. I knew it was something trivial but I could not figure it out. :)